# Python Pandas dataframe is not including all duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, dataframe

I'm basically trying to create a Pandas dataframe (`CQUAD_mech_loads`) that is a subset of a larger dataframe (`CQUAD_Mech`). This subset dataframe is essentially created by filtering based on two conditions. There are **NO** duplicates in the larger dataframe (`CQUAD_Mech`).

The problem is that my subset dataframe doesn't include the duplicate ID's in the `ELM` column. It does, however, include duplicates in the `LC` column.

`CQUAD_ELM` is a list containing four ID's (`[387522, 387522, 387506, 387507]`). I have duplicate ID's of `387522`. Right now, `CQUAD_mech_loads` is a dataframe with only three rows for the three unique IDs. I want that fourth duplicate ID in there as well.

The code:

```
def get_df(df, col1, cond1, col2='', cond2=0):
        return df[(df[col1] == cond1) & (df[col2].isin(cond2))].reset_index(drop=True)

CQUAD_mech_loads = get_df(CQUAD_Mech,'LC', LC, 'ELM', CQUAD_ELM)
```

The output (where is the other line for `387522`?):

```
       LC     ELM        FX         FY        FXY       
0    3113  387506         0          0          0       
1    3113  387507         0          0          0       
2    3113  387522         0          0          0
```

Comment: don't you want `df[(df[col1].isin(cond1)) & (df[col2].isin(cond2))].reset_index(drop=True)`?

Comment: `cond1` is never a list so I didn't use `isin` before. In any case, I tried using `isin` for both conditions and I still get same result.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dropping the index anyway, you can just set the index to be the column you're interested in and use `.ix` indexing:

```
In [28]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5,5))

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24

In [30]: df.set_index(4, drop=False).ix[[4,4,19,4,24]].reset_index(drop=True)
Out[30]:
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   0   1   2   3   4
2  15  16  17  18  19
3   0   1   2   3   4
4  20  21  22  23  24
```

EDIT: Your current method just finds each distinct col1/col2 pair. If you want to filter on multiple columns, just do it twice, once for each column:

```
In [98]: df.set_index(1, drop=False).ix[[1, 6, 16]].set_index(4, drop=False).ix[[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,19,9]].reset_index(drop=True)
Out[98]:
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   0   1   2   3   4
2   0   1   2   3   4
3   0   1   2   3   4
4   0   1   2   3   4
5   0   1   2   3   4
6   0   1   2   3   4
7   0   1   2   3   4
8  15  16  17  18  19
9   5   6   7   8   9
```

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure how this answers my question. I can see that you're changing the values of certain rows using `ix`, but I don't see how that helps me.

Comment: It's not changing any values; it's selecting them. I just happened to pick 5 again. See edit in a sec.